# Please help to identify if there is meaning of linear variables separation by features in phase space?

Tags: data, model-selection

**Description:**

I have clustering problem with next input:

1. I have truth dataset containing labels for each row of features.
2. I've found that some features can be modified to some phase space,
   where they are clearly distinguishable
   (http://i.prntscr.com/iceOaKW8SdiIs-QWT8UVqg.png) only in case if I select subset containing only a few clusters (n_clusters << n_labels) and no other clusters together within this truth dataset. And for the close items (within space of modified features) it would be harder to distinguish them, lines become closer and closer.

**Questions:**

1. Does this separability give an actual knowledge, allowing to build the model or it's the false way of data understanding (does it make sense to consider using this parameter for the model teaching)?
2. If this separability makes sense and can be interpreted, which model will work better for this situation, does it makes sense to teach the model on the small subsets with distant items and join them somehow?

**UPD:** 
According to my experiments, DBSCAN had shown that this parameter only created additional confusing, as on more rows in the data lines became denser and deviance within one line became larger than the distance between lines.